# Ubuntu Desktop 1st Try

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd, menu

Had no problem with the ISO file and installation on an ASUS Windows 8.1 laptop however after reboot I had 6 entries in my boot menu

```
Windows Boot manager P4 Samsung SSD 850 PRO 128GB
Ubuntu (P4 Samsung SSD 850 PRO 128GB)
Ubuntu (P4 Samsung SSD 850 PRO 128GB)
UEFI: WDC WD2599AAKS-00VSA-01.0
UEFI: WDC WD2599AAKS-00VSA-01.0
UEFI: WDC WD2599AAKS-00VSA-01.0
```

The last 4-6 entries above I think they refer to a USB SSD drive I have attach to my laptop but when I click any I get a black screen full of commands which I don’t understand

The second entry finally got me to the Ubuntu desktop and all was fine there

But after I got stuck and had to reboot I only have the first 3 entries on my boot menu and now the Ubuntu boots to this black screen which I don’t know what to do. I type exit at the prompt and it reboots.

My questions:

- Why I got so many boot entries?
- Now I only have 3 and I can’t get to Ubuntu desktop. What is my next step?
- Perhaps re install? How?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer for the first question, but for the last two questions I think you should change the boot order from BIOS and get the `Ubuntu (P4 Samsung SSD 850 PRO 128GB)` in the first place. By doing so, your computer is going to boot from GRUB and you can choose both Windows and Ubuntu from the GRUB Screen.